# FacebookSDK 4.23.0 complains about GraphRequest v2.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
     }else{
         [login
          logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
          fromViewController:self
          handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
              if (error) {
                  NSLog(@"Process error");
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                  NSLog(@"Cancelled");
              } else {
                  NSLog(@"Logged in");
              }
          }];
     }
 }];
```

A new application on XCode.

Getting this error:

```
FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter
```

Facebook declared v2.9 as the latest Graph API version, why is it still accessing v.24?

Comment: The duplicate found does not answer the v2.4 vs v2.9 question

Comment: Do you have trouble understanding what "starting with" means?

Comment: Apparently I did :D sorry